# Not able to read JSON string via $_GET

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a `jQuery` object and I am using `JSON.stringify()` to convert that object to `JSON string` and pass it to `php` file via `$.get()`.
On the `PHP` side I am using `json_decode()` to convert it `PHP Array`.
But when I `echo` it, it shows nothing on the `console` whereas `echo print_r()` shows `1`. I tried with `POST()` but it was the same problem.

Here is the code snippet

```
var task = {};  // Will be added later.
// Preparing the data to be stored as a file.
var processed = {};
processed["job_id"] = JSON.parse(data).job_id;
processed["task_id"] = JSON.parse(data).task_id;
processed["file_name"] = JSON.parse(data).file;
processed["process"] = task;
console.log(JSON.stringify(processed));
$.get("task.php?processed="+JSON.stringify(processed),function(returndata, status){
    console.log(returndata);
});
```

Code for Php file :

```
<?php   

   include_once("db.php");
   $data = json_decode($_GET["processed"],true);
   echo $data[0]["job_id"]   // This will return a blank line.

?>
```

EDIT

output from `JSON.stringify(processed)`:
`{"job_id":51,"task_id":120,"file_name":"task00.txt","process":{}}`

output from `var_dump($_GET)`:

`array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  string(65) "{"job_id":52,"task_id":127,"file_name":"task00.txt","process":{}}"
}`

Comment: Please post the JSON string you are trying to read.

Comment: @JesseSchokker you mean the output  from `console.log(JSON.stringify(processed))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one JSON object (not array of objects), so have one dimensional array in php and  don't need to use 0 index:

```
<?php   

   include_once("db.php");
   $data = json_decode($_GET["data"],true);
   echo $data["job_id"];

?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($data)` returns `NULL` and what you said also returns a blank line.

Comment: What is `var_dump($_GET);`?

Comment: `array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  string(65) "{"job_id":52,"task_id":127,"file_name":"task00.txt","process":{}}"
}`

Comment: Can you please tell me the reason behind this and from where did "data" came from.
Sorry this is my first time with PHP and JQuery.

Comment: Also "process" is a javascript object, how am I supposed to deal with it?

Comment: I think jQuery move get parameter in url to `data` parameter. Actually you can use `$.get("task.php", processed, function(returndata, status){`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir!